# Problem: finding a basis for this vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My textbook presents the following practice problem:

> Let $\vec{v_1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \vec{v_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \space $ and $H = \{\begin{bmatrix} s \\ s \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} : s \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then every vector in $H$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ because $\begin{bmatrix} s \\ s \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = s\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Is the set $\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}\}$ a basis for $H$?

Our textbook says that a set of vectors $S$ is a basis for a subspace $H$ if:

(i) $S$ is a linearly independent set

(ii) $H = Span(S) = Span\{\vec{s_1}, ..., \vec{s_n}\}$.

I'm struggling to understand why the set $\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}\}$ is not a basis for $H$. I know the first property is satisfied because the two vectors are in fact linearly independent.

I'm guessing the second property is where this fails, but I don't understand why. If the problem statement itself says that "every vector in $H$" can be written as a linear combination of the two vectors $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$, then that by definition implies that $H = Span(S)$, doesn't it?

The textbook argues that this is not a basis for $H$ because $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ aren't even in $H$, but I don't see how that's relevant to the point we're trying to prove.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please note that this is my first linear algebra course, so simple answers would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of $Span$?

Comment: It's all possible linear combinations (set) of the vectors $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$

Comment: Are all these linear combinations in $H$?

Comment: I think so, yes. That's where I'm confused.

Comment: Ok, so the span of $v_1$, and $v_2$, is the set $S=\{c_1 v_1+c_2 v_2:c_1, c_2\in K\}$; for simplicity, let $K$ here be $R$. What if, say, $c_1=0$?

Comment: But then the problem statement is misleading, because it says: "Then every vector in $H$ is a linear combination of $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$". But as your example demonstrates, that's not the case.

Comment: Ok, so the problem states that every vector in $H$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. But, we have to show something else

Comment: Hint: My second comment

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite lost.

Comment: Ok, so we have that each vector in $H$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. However, to satisfy the condition $H=Span(v_1, v_2)$, we also require that $each$ vector of the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$ be in H. It's like the $'if\ and\ only\ if'$ construct

Comment: Ooooh, I think I've got it now. Thank you!

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe By the way, feel free to write up an answer if you'd like. I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

$\{v_1, v_2\}$ cannot be a basis for $H$ simply because these vector do not belong to $H$.

They cannot be a basis either, because we have an isomorphism $\;
K  \longrightarrow H$, $\;s \longmapsto (s,s, 0)$ and the cardinal of a basis is an invariant.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't really helpful, as I don't know what cardinal and invariants mean. Also, your first sentence pretty much just restates what the book said, which I already mentioned was unclear to me. Thanks anyway

Comment: The cardinal of a basis is just the number of vectors in a basis, and it's a fundamental result on vector spaces that all bases have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at both $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ it is not in $H$: Then YOU CAN NOT GENERATE IT.

$H$ is of dimension $1$ and a base of $H$ forms the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

$H$ is a vector line, and two linearly independent vectors generate a vector plane. The line $H$, in this case, is contained in the plane.

In the definition of both generators and base, the vectors are required to be of the set in question.